# I'm getting an infinite loop of requests with a object tag

Tags: javascript, angularjs, svg

In my app I have this loading spinner that is a svg and I wrap inside a tag object with a `data`. Here is a sample:

```
<object
   ng-show="showLoading"
   style="height: 50px; width: 50px;"
   height="100%"
   width="100%"
   type="image/svg+xml"
   data="/assets/images/spinner.svg">
</object>
```

You can see by the `ng-show` that I use angular to tell when to show the loading, but the thing is, at the time it should appears, it doesn't, and if I look at the network tab at chrome dev tools, I get tons of requests to `assets/iamges/spinner.svg` and all canceled, just like the image:

[image: tons of canceled requests]

And the trickiest is that it sometimes happens inside the app, sometimes doesn't, in very different places (because we have this loading spinner as an object in very different places).

What can be possible happening?

Comment: is there a chance you can provide a fiddle ? also, is this object inside of ng-repeat, ng-if or something ? also, what happens if you try with other browser?

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't able to reproduce this in fiddle. But it worked ok in Edge. And it isn't inside any ng-repeat of ng-if